# Extract from string information on date/time

Tags: python, pandas, string, text-mining

I have some texts that generally starts with:

```
“12 minutes ago - There was a meeting...”
“2 hours ago - Apologies for being...”
“1 day ago - It is a sunny day in London...”
```

and so on.
Basically I have information on:

```
Minutes 
Hours
Day (starting from today)
```

I would like to transform this kind of information into valuable time serie information, in order to extract this part and create a new column from that (Datetime).
In my dataset, I have one column (Date) where I have already the date of when the research was performed (for example, today), in this format: 26/05/2020 and when the search was submitted (e.g. 8:41am). 
So if the text starts with “12 minutes ago”, I should have:

```
26/05/2020 - 8:29 (datetime format in Python)
```

And for others:

```
26/05/2020 - 6:41
25/05/2020 - 8:41
```

The important thing is to have something (string, numeric, date format) that I can plot as time series (I would like to see how many texts where posted in terms of time interval).
Any idea on how I could do this?

Comment: Give input and corresponding expected output precisly

Comment: Are you using pandas? If so you should include a sample of your dataframe? and what's your expected output ?

Comment: Yes, I am using pandas. I will add the tag

Comment: My expected output is a date/datetime informaion to be plotted.

Comment: Could you please provide a full example, including all your data?

Comment: I updated the question. I have information about the date when the search has been performed, and the time when the research was submitted. My expected output would be something that I can plot as time series (for example datetime, or just time in case the search was performed in terms of one day).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the format stays simple : `<digits> <unit> ago ...` it's pretty to parse with `"^(\d+) (\w+) ago"`.

Then, once you have `('minutes', '12')` you'll pass these to `timedelta` which accepts every unit as a keyword argument `timedelta(minutes=12)`, you'll do that by passing a mapping `**{unit:value}`

```
def parse(content):
    timeparts = re.search(r"^(\d+) (\w+) ago", content)
    if not timeparts:
        return None, content
    unit = timeparts.group(2).rstrip('s') + 's' # ensure ends with 's'
    #return datetime.now()-timedelta(**{unit:int(timeparts.group(1))})           # Now date
    return datetime(2020,5,26,8,0,0)-timedelta(**{unit:int(timeparts.group(1))}) # Fixed date
```

Demo

```
values = ["12 minutes ago - There was a meeting...","2 hours ago - Apologies for being...","1 day ago - It is a sunny day in London..."]

for value in values:
  res = parse(value)
  print(res)


2020-05-26 07:48:00
2020-05-26 06:00:00
2020-05-25 08:00:00
```

Comment: I have opened a new question as I have been getting some errors. In case you want to have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029790/mins-is-an-invalid-keyword-argument-for-new?noredirect=1#comment109709546_62029790

Answer (score 0):

You should use a natural language processing library for this, like [spaCY](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101) or NLTK

Here is an example of `tokenization` from the link above, showing how spacY breaks down a sentence:

[image]